# How to programmatically post to my own wall on Facebook?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a simple program to post something to my wall on Fcebook in Python. I tried using this example from [pythonforfacebook](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk):

```
import facebook
oauth_access_token = "****"
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_access_token)
me = "****"
profile = graph.get_object(me)
graph.put_object(me, "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
```

I tried going to the developer center and making an App. For "Select how your app integrates with Facebook",I chose "Website with Facebook Login" (I don't actually have a website, I just have a program that should post to my facebook wall, but this is the closest option that matches what I want to do...).

However, when I run this, it says:

```
$ python a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 7, in <module>
    graph.put_object(me, "feed", message="I am writing on my wall!")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/facebook.py", line 140, in put_object
    post_args=data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/facebook.py", line 298, in request
    raise GraphAPIError(response)
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

How can I log in as the user and authorize my App? Am I even taking the right approach? I don't actually have a website, I just have a program, for the website field I literally entered "http://google.com" and it worked.

Comment: Where did you get your oauth token? Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: @CollinGrady: From here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/

Comment: @CollinGrady: Before I got my token from that link, it was giving an error about invalid token, so I assume it's now valid.

Answer (score 3):

I made it work by getting a new token with permissions to post on my wall (specifically, the "publish_actions" permission). I did this by using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), selecting my application in the dropdown menu, pressing "Get Access Token" and checking "publish_actions". The only problem is the token expires after an hour.

Comment: extend your facebook access token by an hour validity to 60 days validity.

see the following url :-
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending

Answer (score 2):

You must authorize the user for `publish_action`/`publish_stream` permission to post on your wall.

---

- If your only task is to post on the wall/ get the basic info; you can use the **APP Access Token** instead of user access token for performing the action once you've authorized the app. To get the App Access Token, you can uuse-

  ```
  GET /oauth/access_token?
    client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials
  ```

  Or, directly from [**here**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/). But do not hard code it in your app (for security reasons)
- Or, if you want to perform other actions too on the user's behalf you can extend the user token to 2 months validity. Read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) for more details

Answer (score 1):

For those of who stumble upon this post after April 24th, Facebook has stopped support for such API calls.

> As of April 24,2018, the publish_actions permission has been removed. Please see the [Breaking Changes Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24) for more details. To provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.